# How can I achieve being able to run cryptdisks_start as normal user?

Tags: ubuntu, luks, crypttab

I have looked at how to be able to imbue in a `crypttab` stanza (referring to a LUKS device) to allow *a specific* user or *any unprivileged* user to map it. Roughly, I am looking for the equivalent of `user` in the mount options in `/etc/fstab` when mapping the LUKS device (i.e. before mounting it).

The only (half way sensible) approach I have come up so far was to let my unprivileged user run a wrapper script which runs `cryptdisks_start` usint its absolute path as `root` without password, but with the name hardcoded in it. Obviously the script permissions make it impossible for the unprivileged user to tamper with it.

Is there a more straightforward solution, perhaps akin to `user` in `fstab`?

This is on Ubuntu 20.04 and so perhaps systemd offers some way to achieve this? After all there is a unit such as `systemd-cryptsetup@<name>.service` being auto-generated by it, based on the entry in `crypttab`.

As a side note: I am aware of pam_exec, but I am currently in the process of pondering which one works better for me. Either way it appears that there is no way to run it without superuser privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing like that in SystemD.

You could use

- `sudo`
- `udisksctl unlock` with a PolKit configuration for certain users or groups

Comment: Oh, excellent. I didn't know about `udiskctl`. Guess I should start sifting through available binaries in my system whose name ends in `ctl` 

Comment: @0xC0000022L And those which start with `systemd-`...